# Atmega328 standalone not working unless Pin1 connected to Arduino RESET

Tags: atmega328

I'm new into this domain field. My principal occupation is as a .NET developer.
I'm trying to do a personal project in which a AtMega328 takes some output from a scale using HX711 and sends a SMS via SIM800L GSM module. Before creating the whole module I tested each part separately with Arduino and the specific modules directly on breadboard. Everything works fine.I created a standalone using the guide from Arduino website(16Mhz crystal, 2x22 picoFarad capacitors, 10k Resistor to PIN1, RX/TX connected to PIN2/3). I designed the circuit using EasyEDA, printed it into pcb and assembled it. The only issue is that, when the standalone is not connected to the Arduino, and powered up by an external 5V source, unless I connected the pin1 to Arduino(connectd to PC)RESET pin, it's not working. I tried to attach a button for RESET to PCB, and connected it to PIN1 and GND, but like this I cannot upload to Atmega328, unless i disconnect the button from 10k Resistor/PIN1 and GND. In the first picture is the standalone which is not working if powered by an externalSource, unless I remove the button and add wire between Arduino-RESET and Atmega-PIN1. In the 2nd picture is my circuit, without HX711 module and in the 3rd picture is my circuit, working only because I connected the ARDUIN-RESET to Atmega328-PIN1 .[![ATmega328 powered by wallplug, not working][2]][2][image: PCB Schema, not working][![PCB schema, working, after connecting PIN1 to Arduino RESET][4]][4]enter image description here][5]][5][[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105125/discussion-on-question-by-andreimusat-atmega328-standalone-not-working-unless-pi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the comments went to chat. Somebody recommended to use decoupling caps as close as possible near the VCC/GND of Atmega. I have 10uF in my workbench, so I used on of these caps and the issue was solved.

Comment: Not having bypass caps can cause some very weird errors. Guess you learn a lesson here, as I did some time ago (-;